# Capturar atualização de mensagens automaticamente no front-end

Tags: javascript, thread

Gostaria de saber como é feito o processo de captura de atualizações de mensagens e posts (back-end) automaticamente pelo font-end (Como o realizado pelo facebook). Alguém tem idéia?

Isso é feito através de threads no js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

São 3 linhas gerais, a saber:

a. um timeout recursivo procurando por novas informações. quando essas informações existem, elas são exibidas. essa abordagem é mais comum por ser mais simples de implementar, mas não é recomendada pois não é escalável, ou seja, num ambiente com milhares de usuários serão realizadas milhares de requisições * N segundos, sua maioria desnecessárias, aumentando o gasto com banda e infra-estrutura.

b. ajax comet. é uma técnica que deixa uma conexão http aberta de forma que a aplicação consegue enviar informações para o navegador mesmo depois de algum tempo (em geral conexões http duram apenas poucos segundos, ajax comet consiste em burlar essa característica do http). procure por ajax comet associado a linguagem que você programa num mecanismo de busca que você encontrará vários tutoriais.

c. websocket. está disponível apenas em navegadores modernos. é um novo protocolo e ele permite comunicação ida e volta com o navegador (é a abordagem que todos utilizaremos num futuro próximo, hoje ela tem o problema de não funcionar nos navegadores antigos).

nota 1: o facebook utiliza uma mesclagem entre a e b. utiliza basicamente comet mas quando a atividade diminui ele fecha a conexão e altera para um timeout recursivo que também morre depois de um tempo. depois de muito tempo de inatividade ele só atualiza quando o usuário interage com a página.

nota 2: cada um desses caminhos tem diversas técnicas com vantagens e desvantagens. dá uma olhada aqui sobre ajax comet, fica bem esclarecido:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-reverseajax1/